# How can I optimize the following GitHub workflow for my requirement?

Tags: .net, github, .net-core, github-actions, github-for-windows

I'm tasked to automate a dotnet build and deployment process on GitHub. The engineers were manually building the solution on VScode and copy-paste the artifacts onto dev server(IIS app pools).

There are three components - UI, Services and Reports. I've written a workflow wherein I build all the three components under a single build step and then upload it to a 'deploy' folder I created earlier, which I can then download. When I was writing this workflow, the devs were working on reports component.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'Quest_Cicd_Test'
jobs:
  windows_job:
    runs-on: [windows-2019]
    steps:
    - name: checkout repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
      with:
        vs-version: '15.0'
    - name: Check file exists
      run: |
        cd D:\a\CS\
        mkdir Deploy_UI
        mkdir Deploy_Services
        mkdir Deploy_Reports
        echo "ALL Deploy folders created"
    - name: Setup dotnet
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
       dotnet-version: '5.0.407'
    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: Nuget/setup-nuget@v1
      with: 
        nuget-version: '6.0.2'
    - name: Before Script
      run:
         git config --system core.longpaths true
    - name: Cache NuGet Packages
      uses: actions/cache@v1
      id: cache
      with:
        path: ~/.nuget/packages
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
    - name: NuGet Restore
      if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: nuget restore ./WBC.sln
    - name: Build Dotnet Framework Project
      run: |
        dotnet add package Microsoft.Report.Viewer --version 11.0.0
        msbuild ./WBC.UI.Host.Web/WBC.UI.Host.Web.csproj /p:GenerateSerializationAssemblies=Off /t:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
        msbuild ./WBC.Services.WCFHost/WBC.Services.WCFHost.csproj /p:GenerateSerializationAssemblies=Off /t:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile.pubxml
        nuget install ./WBC.UI.Reporting.Web/packages.config -Source http://nuget.org/api/v2
        msbuild ./WBC.UI.Reporting.Web/WBC.UI.Reporting.Web.csproj /p:GenerateSerializationAssemblies=Off /t:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=NewProfile.pubxml
    - name: Upload build result to deploy folder
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: CS-artifacts
        path: D:\a\CS\Deploy_Reports
        retention-days: 6
        
    - name: Download the artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
```

What I intend to do is to optimise my workflow wherein,

- Divide my workflow into two parts - I use any windows runner upto build process and then I use a self-hosted runner (which is the dev server I mentioned earlier) for deployment of artifacts.
- I get to choose which component to build depending on the nature of PR's, whether it is for UI, services or reports component and then build only that component.
- Pass on the artifacts over to the dev server, where I can deploy them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two jobs. The first (build) one would run on an hosted agent. The second one (deploy) should use your self-hosted agent (the dev server, where you downloaded and installed the github runner application).

The workflow should be something like

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: build job
    runs-on: [windows-2019]
    steps:

        # the steps to build 

      - name: Upload build result 
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: CS-artifacts
          path: D:\a\CS\Deploy_Reports
          retention-days: 6

  deploy:
    name: deploy job
    runs-on: [the-tag-you-associated-on-the-dev-server-runner]
    needs: build
    steps:      

      - name: Download build result
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: CS-artifacts
          path: D:\a\CS\Deploy_Reports

      # The steps to publish
```

To chose the component, you may use separate workflows, and add a path condition on the trigger. For the UIcomponent, it might be something like

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'Quest_Cicd_Test'
    paths:
      - ./WBC.UI.Host.Web/*
      # Add other path that impact the UI component
```